# How can I add a reference to a C-based DLL in my C# application?

Tags: c#, c, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I used Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 to create a C# application, and now I want to use a C-based DLL.

How can I add a reference to that C-based DLL to my C# application in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation have you read and what don't you understand in the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add a reference to a native (unmanaged) DLL in either a C# or VB.NET project. That is simply not supported. References only work for other *managed* DLLs (i.e., those you might write in C# or VB.NET, or even C++/CLI).

However, you *can* still make use of the code in that DLL. The trick is to call the functions it provides dynamically at runtime using the same P/Invoke syntax that you use to call functions from the Win32 API.

For example, assume you have the following code compiled into a DLL using C++:

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) void AddNumbers(int a, int b, int* result)
{
    *result = (a + b);
}
}
```

Now, assuming that you compiled that DLL to a file named `test.dll`, you could call that function by adding the following code to your C# application:

```
[DllImport("test.dll"), CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void AddNumbers(int a, int b, out int result);

public int AddNumbers_Wrapper(int a, int b)
{
    int result;
    AddNumbers(a, b, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Or in VB.NET, since you're apparently using that (despite all indications in the question):

```vb
<DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Shared Function AddNumbers(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer, _
                                  ByRef result As Integer)
End Function

Public Function AddNumbers_Wrapper(ByVal a As Integer, _
                                   ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    AddNumbers(a, b, result)
    Return result
End Function
```

Make sure that you set the [`CallingConvention`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx) field of the `DllImport` attribute appropriately, depending on the calling convention of your unmanaged method.

[Here's a more detailed tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx) on how to get started with P/Invoke on Microsoft's site.

Comment: I download that component http://www.pinvoke.net/.
How can i add that pinvoke in my VB2008

Comment: @panchalbhargav: I have no idea. I've never used their tools because I find it easier to write the definitions myself; I've found lots of errors on that site. Did you try reading the instructions on the PInvoke website?

Comment: You don't need the pinvoke.net component, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104.aspx has examples for the VB.NET Syntax

Comment: Oh, you're using VB.NET? The question *clearly* said C#, even before I edit it... I'll add both to my answer.

Comment: @cody you need to make the calling conventions match up

Comment: How can i load c base dll file in my project in VB2008

Comment: @David: Good catch. I'm in the habit of always using `_stdcall` when writing Windows code, so I forget that's not actually the default.

Comment: @panchal: You don't need to "load" the DLL file; the CLR takes care of that automatically. All you need is the `DllImport` declarations for each function that you want to call.

Comment: Thank You for Reply Me
I got Solution